# Save a column which is based on the primary key column simultaneously in a table by JPA

Tags: database, jpa

I have a table defined below:

| Column | Type | Constraint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | VARCHAR(36) | primary key |
| CREATE_TIME | BIGINT |  |
| RES_ID | VARCHAR(64) |  |
| NAME | VARCHAR(255) |  |
| UPDATE_TIME | BIGINT |  |

, where RES_ID is generated based on ID.
For example, ID is 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', then RES_ID is 'res_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' where 'res_' is a constant string.
For now, if I want to save a new record, I have to save it twice because ID is an auto-generated UUID string and only if the ID is determined, can RES_ID be generated and be saved into DB.
Is there anyone knows how to make a connection between ID and RES_ID, so that when I write:

```
repository.save(record);
```

, both ID and RES_ID will be filled and saved into DB automatically and correctly.
Anyone who knows this question, please tell me.
Thank you!

Comment: Why even save `RES_ID` in the table if it can be determined directly from `ID`?

Comment: @Zakaria That is a long story why connections between two models are represented by the ‘RES_ID’. For now, I have to follow the restrictions.